# Avoid getting power poles when extracting trees in GlobalMapper

Tags: lidar, feature-extraction, global-mapper

I am using GlobalMapper V21 and trying to extract trees from a municipal dataset.  The classification isn't very good as I see building outline points being considered ground or high vegetation, so I am stepping back to reclassify points.

When I have done that I am trying to extract the medium and high vegetation points but I keep getting all the power poles as well.  I thought about using intensity to differentiate a power pole from tree canopy but not sure if that would work as when I am looking at the intensity of the power pole I am getting similar values to the trees.

Any suggestions on how to get just trees and not power poles?

Comment: Set your 'Class Groups' https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/knowledgebase/global-mapper-21-1/Lidar_Module/Lidar_class_properties.htm?Highlight=class%20group#class_groups

Comment: Those are already set to use medium and high vegetation to classify power poles/lines.  Does it have to be one or the other, ie. power poles or trees but not both?

Comment: this is the method we have done in the past > https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f058/82ba4a99498b798075d32be46c57c1d609da.pdf (page 1002) vertical density and subtract that out

Comment: I'm trying to do this in Global Mapper using it's settings, so the referenced document is a bit over my head and I am not sure how to translate it into a process to use in Global Mapper within its dialog boxes and fields.

Comment: If you have purchased GlobalMapper, why not ask their tech support group? If you have not, you should; it's well worth the money.